# Как в vue предать this в event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, javascript-events

При загрузке Vue я вызываю метод `suggestInit`.
При создании слушателя suggestView-события select `this === Vue`.
При срабатывании события в коде `this == null`.
Сейчас я использую обращение к экземпляру Vue через объявленную переменную app, но хотелось бы использовать this.
Как передать в тело события this?

```
methods: function() {
    suggestInit: function () {
        // Создаем выпадающую панель с поисковыми подсказками
        new ymaps.SuggestView('address', {results: 5}).events.add('select', function (e) {
            app.device.address = e.get('item').value;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вынесите функцию-обработчик в отдельную переменную и используйте `bind`

```
    suggestInit: function () {
        const handler = function (e) {
            // this тут равен экземпляру компонента
            app.device.address = e.get('item').value;
        }
        // Создаем выпадающую панель с поисковыми подсказками
        new ymaps.SuggestView('address', {results: 5})
            .events.add('select', handler.bind(this));
    }
```

Либо стрелочную ф-цию

```
    suggestInit: function () {
        // тогда bind не нужен
        const handler = e => {
            // this тут равен экземпляру компонента
            app.device.address = e.get('item').value;
        }
        // Создаем выпадающую панель с поисковыми подсказками
        new ymaps.SuggestView('address', {results: 5})
            .events.add('select', handler);
    }
```

Comment: В стрелочной и выносить функцию не нужно

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev можно выносить, можно не выносить. Дело вкуса